# Only index.html file is accessed in Virtual Box LAMP server

Tags: url, server, apache2, virtual-machine, virtualhost

Installed Oracle VirtualBox VM (LAMP) on Windows 8.1

**HOSTS file** edited for hostname to the loop back IP address

```
127.0.0.1    techbox.test
```

**techbox.conf** file configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
ServerName techbox
ServerAlias *.test
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Only `index.html` is working:
http://techbox.test:8080/index.html

Even `basics.html` file in the same vboxshare folder is notworking:
http://techbox.test:8080/basics.html

**Error message**:

> Not Found.
>   The requested URL /basics.html was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at techbox.test Port 8080

Can someone help in simple way (I am not technical)?

Answer (score 0):

I created an `index.html` file as part of installation and testing

```
john@techbox:/media/sf_vboxshare$ touch index.html
```

Then, I copied it to root directory

```
john@techbox:/etc/apache2$ sudo cp -R /media/sf_vboxshare/* /var/www/html
```

It is because, the current configuration is to render only the files physically **copied** to root folder.

So, the other files I created in `sf_vboxeshare` was **not** copied to the root folder `/var/www/html` as such those are not rendered to the browser.